# .NET Core Runtime backward compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-1.0

I need to install on a Windows Server 2012 the .NET Core Runtime for a webapp written with version 1.1. Can I install the .NET Core Runtime 2.0?

I didn't find a clear answer at my question. 
Here someone raised a similar question 
https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/4241

and here the official .NET Core guidance about runtime versioning
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/build/distribution-packaging), .NET Core versions can be installed side by side:

> While there is a single host, most of the other components are in versioned directories (2,3,5,6). These means multiple versions can be present on the system since they are installed side-by-side.

Comment: yes I know it, but in order to save disk-space and tidy up the system can I just install the latest one?

Comment: Why would you do that. The app is written for 1.1. Use 1.1. If you want to use 2.0, build the app for 2.0. Space is not an argument as it is cheap

Comment: @elciopa for 1.x and 2.0 you are out of luck. Rolling forward is only a feature in 2.1, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-2-1#roll-forward

Comment: @LexLi wooow looks great! Usually I hate having 10 differents runtimes installed... That's a great news. Thanks for you comment.